# Javascript Disable a button or ID on start up

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 Clickable Items. One is a button and 2 are ids with image and text that are clickable.

I have searched around, but the specific question I have is how do I disable the 2 ids on startup until I click the button.

Eg:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

This is enabled and will be disabled when I click, which I have disabled after click working

How do I disable the following IDs in javascript on startup until the above button is clicked.

```
id = "a"
id = "b"
```

Thanks in advance

Sorry for lack of markup, I cannot seem to get my html to display here.

I hope this is clear

Comment: Can you explain what kind of elements will have those above mentioned `id`s? Because enabling/disabling them depends on what kind of an element it is. For eg: it is not possible to disable a `<div>` element. Since you have mentioned that they are images which can be clickable, are they `<img>` tags?

Comment: Please show enough of your HTML, CSS and JavaSCript that we can reproduce your problem. See the "[MCVE]," and "[ask]," guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

this code disables IDs "a" and "b" and adds a function to undo it.

```
<script>
     var nodes;
     nodes = document.getElementById("a").getElementsByTagName('*');
     for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].disabled = true;
     }
     nodes = document.getElementById("b").getElementsByTagName('*');
     for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].disabled = true;
     }


  function reDisplayIds(){
     nodes = document.getElementById("a").getElementsByTagName('*');
     for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].disabled = false;
     }
     nodes = document.getElementById("b").getElementsByTagName('*');
     for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].disabled = false;
     }
  }
<script>
```

make your button activate that fucntion.

```
<button onclick="reDisplayIds()"></button>
```

Comment: This solution does not enable/disable the elements; it hides them from the user. This is not what is asked for.